# Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes

Tags: r, import, dataframe, r-faq

I have very large tables (30 million rows) that I would like to load as a dataframes in R.  `read.table()` has a lot of convenient features, but it seems like there is a lot of logic in the implementation that would slow things down.  In my case, I am assuming I know the types of the columns ahead of time, the table does not contain any column headers or row names, and does not have any pathological characters that I have to worry about.

I know that reading in a table as a list using `scan()` can be quite fast, e.g.:

```
datalist <- scan('myfile',sep='\t',list(url='',popularity=0,mintime=0,maxtime=0)))
```

But some of my attempts to convert this to a dataframe appear to decrease the performance of the above by a factor of 6:

```
df <- as.data.frame(scan('myfile',sep='\t',list(url='',popularity=0,mintime=0,maxtime=0))))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  Or quite possibly completely different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 501, accepted):

**An update, several years later**

This answer is old, and R has moved on.  Tweaking [`read.table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/read.table) to run a bit faster has precious little benefit.  Your options are:

1. Using [`vroom`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/01/vroom-1-1-0/) from the tidyverse package `vroom` for importing data from csv/tab-delimited files directly into an R tibble. See [Hector's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56030403/9555388).
2. Using [`fread`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/fread) in [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) for importing data from csv/tab-delimited files directly into R. See [mnel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058684/134830).
3. Using [`read_table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/topics/read_table) in [`readr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html) (on CRAN from April 2015).  This works much like `fread` above.  The *readme* in the link explains the difference between the two functions (`readr` currently claims to be "1.5-2x slower" than `data.table::fread`).
4. [`read.csv.raw`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/iotools/topics/read.csv.raw) from [`iotools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iotools/index.html) provides a third option for quickly reading CSV files.
5. Trying to store as much data as you can in databases rather than flat files.  (As well as being a better permanent storage medium, data is passed to and from R in a binary format, which is faster.) [`read.csv.sql`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/topics/read.csv.sql) in the [`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) package, as described in [JD Long's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1820610/134830), imports data into a temporary SQLite database and then reads it into R.  See also: the [`RODBC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) package, and the reverse depends section of the [`DBI` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html) page. [`MonetDB.R`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonetDB.R/index.html) gives you a data type that pretends to be a data frame but is really a MonetDB underneath, increasing performance.  Import data with its [`monetdb.read.csv`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MonetDB.R/topics/monetdb.read.csv) function.  [`dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) allows you to work directly with data stored in several types of database.
6. Storing data in binary formats can also be useful for improving performance.  Use `saveRDS`/`readRDS` (see below), the [`h5`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/h5/index.html) or [`rhdf5`](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) packages for HDF5 format, or `write_fst`/`read_fst` from the [`fst`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fst) package.

---

**The original answer**

There are a couple of simple things to try, whether you use read.table or scan.

1. Set `nrows`=*the number of records in your data* (`nmax` in `scan`).
2. Make sure that `comment.char=""` to turn off interpretation of comments.
3. Explicitly define the classes of each column using `colClasses` in `read.table`.
4. Setting `multi.line=FALSE` may also improve performance in scan.

If none of these thing work, then use one of the [profiling packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) to determine which lines are slowing things down.  Perhaps you can write a cut down version of `read.table` based on the results.

The other alternative is filtering your data before you read it into R.

Or, if the problem is that you have to read it in regularly, then use these methods to read the data in once, then save the data frame as a binary blob with <del>[`save`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/save)</del> [`saveRDS`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/saveRDS), then next time you can retrieve it faster with <del>[`load`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/load)</del> `readRDS`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Richie.  I did a little testing, and it seems that the performance gains with using the nrow and colClasses options for read.table are quite modest.  For example, reading a ~7M row table takes 78s without the options, and 67s with the options. (note: the table has 1 character column, 4 integer columns, and I read using comment.char='' and stringsAsFactors=FALSE).

Using save() and load() when possible is a great tip - once stored with save(), that same table takes only 12s to load.

Comment: The "feather" package has a new binary format that plays nice with Python's pandas data frames

Comment: I think maybe you need to update your post again with regards to the package `feather`. For reading data `feather` is much faster than `fread`. For example on a 4GB dataset I just loaded `read_feather` was about 4.5 times faster than `fread`. For saving data `fwrite` is still faster. https://blog.dominodatalab.com/the-r-data-i-o-shootout/

Comment: But the file sizes are much larger for feather than with RDS. I don't think it supports compression.  The RDS file is 216 MB and the feather file is 4GB.  So `feather` is faster for reading but it uses a lot more storage space.

Comment: @Zboson If you need to store data frame in a file that can be accessed from both R and Python, then `feather` is a good option. If you only care about being able to read your data in R, `rds` is preferable.

Comment: A fairly new package that hasn't been mentioned here is `iotools`. It has both a fast read capability and chunking.

Comment: `data.table` is like 30 times faster than `read.table` (not to mention it avoids any redundant data copying) and 10 times faster for displaying the data in console.

Comment: Worth noting that the `arrow` package implements feather with a more reliable API. But their `read_parquet()` should definitely on your list: http://arrow.apache.org/blog/2019/08/08/r-package-on-cran/

Comment: It's been mentioned below, but vroom doesn't actually read in the data immediately. It reads it in as it's used, so the initial timing is sort of deceptive. This may be optimal in some situations, but if you're actually going to use all your data there are good reasons to use data.table::fread over vroom.

Comment: @RichieCotton: on your comment to Zboson that RDS is only for R, you may want to update  your thoughts about this. As the `pyreadr.read_r` in python reads RDS files too.

Answer (score 306):

Here is an example that utilizes `fread` from `data.table` 1.8.7

The examples come from the help page to `fread`, with the timings on my windows XP Core 2 duo E8400.

```
library(data.table)
# Demo speedup
n=1e6
DT = data.table( a=sample(1:1000,n,replace=TRUE),
                 b=sample(1:1000,n,replace=TRUE),
                 c=rnorm(n),
                 d=sample(c("foo","bar","baz","qux","quux"),n,replace=TRUE),
                 e=rnorm(n),
                 f=sample(1:1000,n,replace=TRUE) )
DT[2,b:=NA_integer_]
DT[4,c:=NA_real_]
DT[3,d:=NA_character_]
DT[5,d:=""]
DT[2,e:=+Inf]
DT[3,e:=-Inf]
```

## standard read.table

```
write.table(DT,"test.csv",sep=",",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
cat("File size (MB):",round(file.info("test.csv")$size/1024^2),"\n")    
## File size (MB): 51 

system.time(DF1 <- read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE))        
##    user  system elapsed 
##   24.71    0.15   25.42
# second run will be faster
system.time(DF1 <- read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE))        
##    user  system elapsed 
##   17.85    0.07   17.98
```

## optimized read.table

```
system.time(DF2 <- read.table("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",quote="",  
                          stringsAsFactors=FALSE,comment.char="",nrows=n,                   
                          colClasses=c("integer","integer","numeric",                        
                                       "character","numeric","integer")))


##    user  system elapsed 
##   10.20    0.03   10.32
```

## fread

```
require(data.table)
system.time(DT <- fread("test.csv"))                                  
 ##    user  system elapsed 
##    3.12    0.01    3.22
```

## sqldf

```
require(sqldf)

system.time(SQLDF <- read.csv.sql("test.csv",dbname=NULL))             

##    user  system elapsed 
##   12.49    0.09   12.69

# sqldf as on SO

f <- file("test.csv")
system.time(SQLf <- sqldf("select * from f", dbname = tempfile(), file.format = list(header = T, row.names = F)))

##    user  system elapsed 
##   10.21    0.47   10.73
```

## ff / ffdf

```
 require(ff)

 system.time(FFDF <- read.csv.ffdf(file="test.csv",nrows=n))   
 ##    user  system elapsed 
 ##   10.85    0.10   10.99
```

## In summary:

```
##    user  system elapsed  Method
##   24.71    0.15   25.42  read.csv (first time)
##   17.85    0.07   17.98  read.csv (second time)
##   10.20    0.03   10.32  Optimized read.table
##    3.12    0.01    3.22  fread
##   12.49    0.09   12.69  sqldf
##   10.21    0.47   10.73  sqldf on SO
##   10.85    0.10   10.99  ffdf
```

Comment: Great answer, and the benchmarking holds in other contexts.  Just read in a 4GB file in well under a minute with `fread`.  Had tried reading it in with the base R functions and it took about 15 hours.

Comment: my benchmark suggest even greater speed advantages for read.csv in data.table.  note that data.table is not standard R, but (sadly) "just" nicely shared by its creators on CRAN.  it is not even deemed standard enough to make the common R package list, much less qualify as a replacement for data frames.  it has a lot of advantages, but also some very counterintuitive aspects.  you may want to use as.data.frame(fread.csv("test.csv")) with the package to get back into the standard R data frame world.

Comment: @mnel could you please re-run the benchmark and include `readr`?

Comment: Second @jangorecki. Also, given `fread` has some real competitors now, could be useful to add benchmarks for optimized `fread` usage -- specifying `colClasses`, etc.

Comment: @jangorecji @ MichaelChirico the code given is entirely reproductible so it is straight forward to simulate readr... rerunning the code, on my machine elapsed time is twice as fast if not more for most results eventhough I am running it over a network (and well updated versions as it is some time now)... and with readr I am at 7s but also under a second when I run a second time (0.66s), I suspect there is some caching or some bottle neck in the network. fread for the fastest solution shown here is at 2s on my side for comparaison (first time running at 8.69s) for some reason slower)

Answer (score 261):

I didn't see this question initially and asked a similar question a few days later. I am going to take my previous question down, but I thought I'd add an answer here to explain how I used `sqldf()` to do this.

There's been [little bit of discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-August/138315.html) as to the best way to import 2GB or more of text data into an R data frame. Yesterday I wrote a [blog post](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/?p=416) about using `sqldf()` to import the data into SQLite as a staging area, and then sucking it from SQLite into R. This works really well for me. I was able to pull in 2GB (3 columns, 40mm rows) of data in < 5 minutes. By contrast, the `read.csv` command ran all night and never completed.

Here's my test code:

Set up the test data:

```
bigdf <- data.frame(dim=sample(letters, replace=T, 4e7), fact1=rnorm(4e7), fact2=rnorm(4e7, 20, 50))
write.csv(bigdf, 'bigdf.csv', quote = F)
```

I restarted R before running the following import routine:

```
library(sqldf)
f <- file("bigdf.csv")
system.time(bigdf <- sqldf("select * from f", dbname = tempfile(), file.format = list(header = T, row.names = F)))
```

I let the following line run all night but it never completed:

```
system.time(big.df <- read.csv('bigdf.csv'))
```

Comment: Hi. How woul you use it as an input for other packages such as zoo, designed to be used with all data simultenously?

Comment: @skan the end object is a data frame. So you have to convert it to a zoo object in order to use it with zoo. Look at the examples in the zoo docs for illustrations.

Comment: @JD Long. Hi, the problem is that when you convert it to a zoo object it tries to fit it on the memory. If it's too big it produces an error. And if the result of the zoo object (for example an aggregation of two series) is also too it would need to be a sql or ff object too.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with sqldf. I've created a simple 1GB file on disk (with 2 numerical columns) and used DTSQL <- read.csv.sql("f2.txt",dbname=tempfile())  and it tries to load the whole data on memory.  Tomorrow I'll try ff and revoscaler instead.

Comment: This method does not seem to handle quoted data properly (e.g. if all fields are quoted and quotes in fields are double quoted).  The sqldf docs touch on the issue, but don't seem to present a solution.

Comment: @JDLong I probably slept through this in school, but what are "40mm rows"? Millimeter?

Comment: @what m is thousand so mm is thousand thousand, or million. I probably should have capitalized it as MM. But I find that just about any million abbreviation can be confusing to someone if you have a diverse enough audience. In my attempt to be overly verbose, I'm sorry that I made it more confusing! 

http://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-does-m-and-mm-stand-for

Comment: Unfortunately read.cvs.sql doesn't handle NULLs or empty strings in the file correctly...

Answer (score 81):

Strangely, no one answered the bottom part of the question for years even though this is an important one -- `data.frame`s are simply lists with the right attributes, so if you have large data you don't want to use `as.data.frame` or similar for a list. It's much faster to simply "turn" a list into a data frame in-place:

```
attr(df, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(length(df[[1]]))
class(df) <- "data.frame"
```

This makes no copy of the data so it's immediate (unlike all other methods). It assumes that you have already set `names()` on the list accordingly.

[As for loading large data into R -- personally, I dump them by column into binary files and use `readBin()` - that is by far the fastest method (other than mmapping) and is only limited by the disk speed. Parsing ASCII files is inherently slow (even in C) compared to binary data.]

Comment: Using `tracmem` suggests that `attr<-` and `class<-` make copies internally. `bit::setattr` or `data.table::setattr` will not.

Comment: Maybe you used the wrong order? There is no copy if you use `df=scan(...); names(df)=...; attr...; class...` - see `tracemem()` (tested in R 2.15.2)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you dump the large data by column into binary files?

Comment: would you mind providing also an example please?

Answer (score 33):

This was previously [asked on **R-Help**](http://markmail.org/message/zeew2gr2x77cglcv#query:r-project%20quickly%20read%20large%20file+page:1+mid:bovcytjhdkzmefru+state:results), so that's worth reviewing.

One suggestion there was to use `readChar()` and then do string manipulation on the result with `strsplit()` and `substr()`.  You can see the logic involved in readChar is much less than read.table.

I don't know if memory is an issue here, but you might also [want to take a look at the **HadoopStreaming** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HadoopStreaming/index.html).  This [uses Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop), which is a MapReduce framework designed for dealing with large data sets.  For this, you would use the hsTableReader function.  This is an example (but it has a learning curve to learn Hadoop):

```
str <- "key1\t3.9\nkey1\t8.9\nkey1\t1.2\nkey1\t3.9\nkey1\t8.9\nkey1\t1.2\nkey2\t9.9\nkey2\"
cat(str)
cols = list(key='',val=0)
con <- textConnection(str, open = "r")
hsTableReader(con,cols,chunkSize=6,FUN=print,ignoreKey=TRUE)
close(con)
```

The basic idea here is to break the data import into chunks.  You could even go so far as to use one of the parallel frameworks (e.g. snow) and run the data import in parallel by segmenting the file, but most likely for large data sets that won't help since you will run into memory constraints, which is why map-reduce is a better approach.

Comment: I just did a quick test and readChar does seem to be much faster than even readLines for some inexplicable reason. However, it is still slow as sin compared to a simple C test. At the simple task of reading 100 megs, R is about 5 - 10x slower than C

Comment: Don't understand your point.  The point of Hadoop is to handle very large data, which is what the question was about.

Comment: Despite the name, hsTableReader doesn't have anything to do with Hadoop per se, it's for processing large data in pieces.  It reads from con, a chunk of rows at a time, and passes each chunk as a data.frame to FUN for processing. With ignoreKey=FALSE, it does some extra grouping by key (the entry in the first column), which is relevant to Map/Reduce approaches.

Comment: Hi. How would you use this Hadoop data as an input for other packages such as zoo, designed to be used with all data simultenously?

Answer (score 15):

An alternative is to use the `vroom` package. Now on CRAN.
`vroom` doesn't load the entire file, it indexes where each record is located, and is read later when you use it.

> Only pay for what you use.

See [Introduction to vroom](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom), [Get started with vroom](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/vroom.html) and the [vroom benchmarks](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html).

The basic overview is that the initial read of a huge file, will be much faster, and subsequent modifications to the data may be slightly slower. So depending on what your use is, it could be the best option.

See a simplified example from [vroom benchmarks](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html) below, the key parts to see is the super fast read times, but slightly sower operations like aggregate etc..

```
package                 read    print   sample   filter  aggregate   total
read.delim              1m      21.5s   1ms      315ms   764ms       1m 22.6s
readr                   33.1s   90ms    2ms      202ms   825ms       34.2s
data.table              15.7s   13ms    1ms      129ms   394ms       16.3s
vroom (altrep) dplyr    1.7s    89ms    1.7s     1.3s    1.9s        6.7s
```

Answer (score 10):

I am reading data very quickly using the new `arrow` package. It appears to be in a fairly early stage.

Specifically, I am using the **parquet** columnar format. This converts back to a `data.frame` in R, but you can get even deeper speedups if you do not. This format is convenient as it can be used from Python as well.

My main use case for this is on a fairly restrained RShiny server. For these reasons, I prefer to keep data attached to the Apps (i.e., out of SQL), and therefore require small file size as well as speed.

This linked article provides benchmarking and a good overview. I have quoted some interesting points below.

https://ursalabs.org/blog/2019-10-columnar-perf/

### File Size

> That is, the Parquet file is half as big as even the gzipped CSV. One of the reasons that the Parquet file is so small is because of dictionary-encoding (also called “dictionary compression”). Dictionary compression can yield substantially better compression than using a general purpose bytes compressor like LZ4 or ZSTD (which are used in the FST format). Parquet was designed to produce very small files that are fast to read.

### Read Speed

> When controlling by output type (e.g. comparing all R data.frame outputs with each other) we see the the performance of Parquet, Feather, and FST falls within a relatively small margin of each other. The same is true of the pandas.DataFrame outputs. data.table::fread is impressively competitive with the 1.5 GB file size but lags the others on the 2.5 GB CSV.

---

### Independent Test

I performed some independent benchmarking on a simulated dataset of 1,000,000 rows. Basically I shuffled a bunch of things around to attempt to challenge the compression. Also I added a short text field of random words and two simulated factors.

#### Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(OpenRepGrid)

n <- 1000000

set.seed(1234)
some_levels1 <- sapply(1:10, function(x) paste(LETTERS[sample(1:26, size = sample(3:8, 1), replace = TRUE)], collapse = ""))
some_levels2 <- sapply(1:65, function(x) paste(LETTERS[sample(1:26, size = sample(5:16, 1), replace = TRUE)], collapse = ""))


test_data <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  sample_n(n, replace = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_all(~ sample(., length(.))) %>%
  mutate(factor1 = sample(some_levels1, n, replace = TRUE),
         factor2 = sample(some_levels2, n, replace = TRUE),
         text = randomSentences(n, sample(3:8, n, replace = TRUE))
         )
```

#### Read and Write

Writing the data is easy.

```
library(arrow)

write_parquet(test_data , "test_data.parquet")

# you can also mess with the compression
write_parquet(test_data, "test_data2.parquet", compress = "gzip", compression_level = 9)
```

Reading the data is also easy.

```
read_parquet("test_data.parquet")

# this option will result in lightning fast reads, but in a different format.
read_parquet("test_data2.parquet", as_data_frame = FALSE)
```

I tested reading this data against a few of the competing options, and did get slightly different results than with the article above, which is expected.

[image: benchmarking]

This file is nowhere near as large as the benchmark article, so maybe that is the difference.

#### Tests

- **rds:** test_data.rds (20.3 MB)
- **parquet2_native:** (14.9 MB with higher compression and `as_data_frame = FALSE`)
- **parquet2:** test_data2.parquet (14.9 MB with higher compression)
- **parquet:** test_data.parquet (40.7 MB)
- **fst2:** test_data2.fst (27.9 MB with higher compression)
- **fst:** test_data.fst (76.8 MB)
- **fread2:** test_data.csv.gz (23.6MB)
- **fread:** test_data.csv (98.7MB)
- **feather_arrow:** test_data.feather (157.2 MB read with `arrow`)
- **feather:** test_data.feather (157.2 MB read with `feather`)

#### Observations

For this particular file, `fread` is actually very fast. I like the small file size from the highly compressed `parquet2` test. I may invest the time to work with the native data format rather than a `data.frame` if I really need the speed up.

Here `fst` is also a great choice. I would either use the highly compressed `fst` format or the highly compressed `parquet` depending on if I needed the speed or file size trade off.

Answer (score 7):

A minor additional points worth mentioning. If you have a very large file you can on the fly calculate the number of rows (if no header) using (where `bedGraph` is the name of your file in your working directory):

```
>numRow=as.integer(system(paste("wc -l", bedGraph, "| sed 's/[^0-9.]*\\([0-9.]*\\).*/\\1/'"), intern=T))
```

You can then use that either in `read.csv` , `read.table` ...

```
>system.time((BG=read.table(bedGraph, nrows=numRow, col.names=c('chr', 'start', 'end', 'score'),colClasses=c('character', rep('integer',3)))))
   user  system elapsed 
 25.877   0.887  26.752 
>object.size(BG)
203949432 bytes
```

Answer (score 6):

Often times I think it is just good practice to keep larger databases inside a database (e.g. Postgres). I don't use anything too much larger than (nrow * ncol) ncell = 10M, which is pretty small; but I often find I want R to create and hold memory intensive graphs only while I query from multiple databases. In the future of 32 GB laptops, some of these types of memory problems will disappear. But the allure of using a database to hold the data and then using R's memory for the resulting query results and graphs still may be useful. Some advantages are:

(1) The data stays loaded in your database. You simply reconnect in pgadmin to the databases you want when you turn your laptop back on.

(2) It is true R can do many more nifty statistical and graphing operations than SQL. But I think SQL is better designed to query large amounts of data than R.

```
# Looking at Voter/Registrant Age by Decade

library(RPostgreSQL);library(lattice)

con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user= "postgres", password="password",
                 port="2345", host="localhost", dbname="WC2014_08_01_2014")

Decade_BD_1980_42 <- dbGetQuery(con,"Select PrecinctID,Count(PrecinctID),extract(DECADE from Birthdate) from voterdb where extract(DECADE from Birthdate)::numeric > 198 and PrecinctID in (Select * from LD42) Group By PrecinctID,date_part Order by Count DESC;")

Decade_RD_1980_42 <- dbGetQuery(con,"Select PrecinctID,Count(PrecinctID),extract(DECADE from RegistrationDate) from voterdb where extract(DECADE from RegistrationDate)::numeric > 198 and PrecinctID in (Select * from LD42) Group By PrecinctID,date_part Order by Count DESC;")

with(Decade_BD_1980_42,(barchart(~count | as.factor(precinctid))));
mtext("42LD Birthdays later than 1980 by Precinct",side=1,line=0)

with(Decade_RD_1980_42,(barchart(~count | as.factor(precinctid))));
mtext("42LD Registration Dates later than 1980 by Precinct",side=1,line=0)
```

Comment: `DuckDB` is a relatively new open-source analytical database available now on CRAN. Very small package while supporting PostGres like SQL commands. It also supports querying `parquet` format files with SQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to contribute Spark-based solution in the simplest form:

```
# Test Data ---------------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(123)
bigdf <-
    data.frame(
        dim = sample(letters, replace = T, 4e7),
        fact1 = rnorm(4e7),
        fact2 = rnorm(4e7, 20, 50)
    )
tmp_csv <- fs::file_temp(pattern = "big_df", ext = ".csv")
readr::write_csv(x = bigdf, file = tmp_csv)

# Spark -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Installing if needed
# sparklyr::spark_available_versions()
# sparklyr::spark_install()

library("sparklyr")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

# Uploading CSV
system.time(tbl_big_df <- spark_read_csv(sc = sc, path = tmp_csv))
```

Spark generated fairly OK results:

```
>> system.time(tbl_big_df <- spark_read_csv(sc = sc, path = tmp_csv))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.278   0.034  11.747
```

This was tested on MacBook Pro with 32GB ram.

## Remarks

Spark, *usually* shouldn't be able to "win" against packages optimised for speed. Nevertheless, I wanted to contribute an answer using Spark:

- For some of the comments and answers where process didn't work using Spark may be a viable alternative
- In a long-run, hammering as much data as possible into `data.frame` may prove problematic later on, when other operations are attempted on that object and hit the performance envelope of architecture

I think that for questions like that, where the task is to handle 1e7 or more rows Spark should be given considerations. Even if it may be possible to "hammer in" that data into a single `data.frame` it's just doesn't feel right. Likely that object will be difficult to work with and create problems when deploying models, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the conventional read.table I feel fread is a faster function. 
Specifying additional attributes like select only the required columns, specifying colclasses and string as factors will reduce the time take to import the file.

```
data_frame <- fread("filename.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,select=c(1,4,5,6,7),colClasses=c("as.numeric","as.character","as.numeric","as.Date","as.Factor"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all above and [readr][1] made the best job. I have only 8gb RAM

Loop for 20 files, 5gb each, 7 columns:

```
read_fwf(arquivos[i],col_types = "ccccccc",fwf_cols(cnpj = c(4,17), nome = c(19,168), cpf = c(169,183), fantasia = c(169,223), sit.cadastral = c(224,225), dt.sitcadastral = c(226,233), cnae = c(376,382)))
```